# plot a daily profile with python

Tags: python, datetime, time, matplotlib, plot

I want to make a daily profile plot: hour vs concentrations. I'm using matplotlib and datetime module.

When I write:

```
import datetime
from pylab import *
b = [datetime.time(12,0), datetime.time(13,0)]
c = [4,5]
plot(b,c)
show()
```

... it doesn't work.

I have to use datetime objects instead of time objects to be able to make the plot:

```
a = [datetime.datetime(2005,5,10,12), datetime.datetime(2005,5,10,13)]
c = [4,5]
plot(a,c)
show()
```

But I really would like to be able to make the plot using time objects instead of datetime...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the matplotlib documentation here:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/dates_api.html

The issue is that matplotlib only knows how to convert the datetime object to a float and it doesn't look there is the same support for datetime.time

Edit:
One possible solution is to just get a default date ('today') and then combine it with the specific time you want if you don't care about the date:

```
import datetime
from pylab import *
d = datetime.date.today()
tt = [datetime.time(12,0), datetime.time(13,0)]
b = []
for t in tt:
    b.append(datetime.datetime.combine(d,t))
c = [4,5]
plot(b,c)
show()
```

Comment: I will do it. Thanks Josh for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Time returns the amount of seconds.

```
>>>print time.time()
1297696979.78

>>>print date.fromtimestamp(today)
2011-02-14
```

Today being a variable I set equal to the current time.time(). I'm not quite sure why you're entering variables into the time() function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using the class datetime.time 
(datetime module), which has the attributes hour, minute, second, microsecond, and tzinfo. I'm only entering hour and minute values.